# Prove that $\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...}(-1+1/n,0)=(-1,0)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that: $$\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...}(-1+1/n,0)=(-1,0)$$

My proof is:

$Let \ a \in \bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...}(-1+1/n,0)$

$ -1+1/n \lt a \lt 0$

$-1\lt-1+1/n \ $

$-1\lt a\lt0$

So any $\ a \in \bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...}(-1+1/n,0) \ $ is also in the interval (-1,0)

Therefore

$\bigcup_{n=1,2,3...}(-1+1/n,0) \subseteq (-1,0)$

$Let \ b  \in (-1,0)$

$-1\lt b \lt 0$

$0 \lt b+1 \lt 1$

Since b+1 is greater than 0 and 1 is a real number, there is a positive integer n such that $n(b+1) \gt 1$ (Archimedean property)

$-1+1/n \lt b \lt 0$

This means any $\ b \in (-1,0) \ $ is in the interval $ 
\ \bigcup_{n=1,2,3...}(-1+1/n,0)$

Therefore

$(-1,0) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1,2,3...}(-1+1/n,0) $

Since $(-1,0) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1,2,3...}(-1+1/n,0) \ $  and   $ \ \bigcup_{n=1,2,3...}(-1+1/n,0) \subseteq (-1,0)$

$$ \bigcup_{n=1,2,3...}(-1+1/n,0) = (-1,0)$$

Is my proof valid?
Also is there a different/more elegant way to prove this?

Comment: You proof is ok, maybe you could exploit the fact that the intervals are increasingly larger and the partial union up to $n$ is embedded in the next $n+1$ interval. So the whole union is just the limit interval.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are sets, the standard approach to proving that $A = B$ is to show that every member of $A$ is a member of $B$ and vice versa. Try to organise  your proof along those lines and explain the steps as you go. As things stand you have just listed a sequence of statements without explaining their relevance to the proof.

Comment: I added some explanations. I hope it is better now. Thank you for the suggestions